# Find all incongruent solutions to $x^2 \equiv 23 \pmod{77}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem

Find all incongruent solutions to $x^2 \equiv 23 \pmod{77}$

---

Using the Chinese Remainder Theorem, I obtained $x^2 \equiv 23 \pmod{7}$ and $x^2 \equiv 23 \pmod{11}$.

For $x^2 \equiv 23 \pmod{7}$, the answers are:
\begin{align}
x \equiv 3 \pmod{7} \\
x \equiv 4 \pmod{7}
\end{align}

For $x^2 \equiv 23 \pmod{11}$, the answers are:
\begin{align}
x \equiv 1 \pmod{11} \\
x \equiv 10 \pmod{11}
\end{align}

But the solutions for $x^2 \equiv 23 \pmod{77}$ are:
\begin{align}
x \equiv 10 \pmod{77} \\
x \equiv 32 \pmod{77} \\
x \equiv 45 \pmod{77} \\
x \equiv 67 \pmod{77}
\end{align}

Why are my answers not the same as the solutions? Can someone help me with this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the given solution, combine congruences in your solution with the Chinese remainder theorem: $3\bmod7\land1\bmod11\iff45\mod77$, etc.

Comment: From what I understand, I will get the answers by solving each pair: $x \equiv 3 \pmod 7$ and $x \equiv 1 \pmod {11}$, $x \equiv 3 \pmod 7$ and $x \equiv 10 \pmod {11}$, $x \equiv 4 \pmod 7$ and $x \equiv 1 \pmod {11}$, $x \equiv 4 \pmod 7$ and $x \equiv 10 \pmod {11}$, right?

Comment: @fish Yes.${}{}{}$

Comment: Thanks for your help!